# Update JSON-file with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

For school I am making this project, where I will need to make it possible for a user to update his/her profile and I have made a simple piece of code, that I actually thought would be able to update the json file. But it isn't working.
So my question is: Can I update my 'users.json' with only Javascript/jQuery or will it be easier/better to use PHP?

My code:

```
<h1>Edit profile</h1>
        <p>Input your email to edit your profile:</p>
        <input type="text" id="validatingEmail" placeholder="Email" required="required">
        <p>Edit your profile here:</p>
        <input type="text" id="newName" placeholder="New name here">
        <input type="text" id="newLastName" placeholder="New last name here">
        <input type="text" id="newMobile" placeholder="New mobile nr. here">
        <input type="text" id="newPassword" placeholder="New password here">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnUpdateProfile">Update Profil</button>

$.getJSON('users.json', function(data){
                var sUsers = JSON.stringify(data);
                var oUsers = JSON.parse(sUsers);

                $(document).on('click', '#btnUpdateProfile', function(){
                    var validatingEmail = $('#validatingEmail').val();
                    var newName = $('#newName').val();
                    var newLastName = $('#newLastName').val();
                    var newMobile = $('#newMobile').val();
                    var newPassword = $('#newPassword').val();
                        for(var i = 0 ; i < oUsers.length ; i++){
                            if(validatingEmail == oUsers[i].email){
                                oUsers[i].name = newName;
                                oUsers[i].lastname = newLastName;
                                oUsers[i].mobile = newMobile;
                                oUsers[i].password = newPassword;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                });
            });

[
{
    "name": "firstname",
    "lastname": "lastname",
    "email": "email",
    "mobile": "12345678",
    "password": "1234"
},
{
    "name": "firstname",
    "lastname": "lastname",
    "email": "email",
    "mobile": "12345678",
    "password": "123"
},
]
```

Comment: You will need a serverside language in order to save the file - javascript in the browser cannot modify the filesystem

Comment: All right. Thanks Steve!

Comment: You can, of course, use JavaScript as a server side language (e.g. via Node.js).

Comment: I haven't worked with Node.js before, and I know some PHP, so I will try doing this with PHP.